# Sorting Month And Year Results In Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, sorting, date, ms-access

I have the following table in Microsoft Access

TransactionDate
Market
Details
Opening
Closing
Size
Profit/Loss

I want to run a query that shows the Profit/Loss for each month.

I have been able get a query that returns the information in the following format

TransactionDate By Month    Sum Of Sum Of Profit/Loss

April 2014                  €1,084.99

April 2015                  €674.33

April 2016                  €2,057.30

August 2014                 €237.59

August 2015                -€267.82

December 2014               €375.88

December 2015              -€1,161.97

February 2015              -€603.87

February 2016              -€124.71

January 2015                €75.11

January 2016               -€1,044.35

But what I want now is for it to display in chronological order as oppose to Alphabetical order.

For example

January 2014

February 2014

March 2014

etc.

Comment: Your date column is defined as String or as Date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will consider that your `TransactionDate` field is defined as **String**

If you want to `order by` this text field in Access, you will have to use `DateValue()` function.

That would give:

```
SELECT TransactionDate FROM yourTable ORDER BY DateValue(TransactionDate)
```

If your field is already formatted as a **Date** field, then simply use `order by TransactionDate` to make it work.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.